# DataGridView.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged throws InvalidProgramException when calling a method

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, .net-2.0

I have a DataGridView that is bound to a DataTable. I was using AutoGenerateColumns=true but I changed it to false so that I could manage the columns myself and then I started getting an InvalidProgramException in the event handler for DataGridView.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged. When this event handler calls another method called CheckFilter() it throws the exception. It does not enter the method when I step through the code so the exception happens when the method is called. CheckFilter() is a private sub with no parameters. The exception message is "Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program". I am using vb.net with .net 2.0 and Visual Studio 2008 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the exception did not come from calling the method but from a for each loop inside the method. I did not specify the type of the loop variable. The for each loop loops through a collection of datarows so I made the loop variable a DataGridViewRow and then the exception went away. I think it must be a bug in the framework or the compiler.